# How do solve the distance between two intervals by using geometry?

Tags: calculus

Like for example if t is time in hours given by

v(t)= *something*

approximate the distance on [first interval, second interval] by using geometry?
I'm sort of leaving the entries blank so that I can do the work myself, I just don't understand what is means by geometry?